# Notation: for strongly-regular graph $(v,k;\lambda, \mu)$, how to interpret "$k(k-\lambda-1)$" and "$\mu(v-k-1)$"?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, definition

Proposition: Let $G=(V,E)$ denote a $(v,k;\lambda, \mu)$ strongly-regular graph. Then $$k(k-\lambda-1)=\mu(v-k-1)$$

The notation is quite overloaded for me. Since $k$ and $\mu$ are parameters, then what does $k(k-\lambda-1)$ and $\mu(v-k-1)$ mean?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of multiplication? :)  The Wikipedia entry for [strongly-regular graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph#Relationship_between_Parameters) walks through the derivation of this relation, making clear that it involves products of quantities.

Comment: this is not funny! hahaha Thanks!!